# How to retrieve multiple column from SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get two column details like this way:

```
    public string GetData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.Connection))
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select TITTLE,VALUE from T_PROJECTS ", con);



            // int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                return reader["TITTLE,VALUE"]?.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a custom class of columns that you want to retrieve, for example,

```
 public class Project
        {
          public int Title { get; set; }
          public string Value { get; set; }         
        }
```

and then like this,

```
 public Project GetData()
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.Connection))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select TITTLE,VALUE from T_PROJECTS ", con);
            Project proObj = new Project();            
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                proObj.Title = reader["TITTLE"].ToString();
                proObj.Value = reader["VALUE"].ToString();
            }

        }
     return proObj;
    }
```

Comment: can i do with out creating class. means like Convert string builder to json type?

Comment: Yes you can do that too

Comment: please help me to convert string bulider to jason type

Comment: @mr.cool Look at this sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554472/create-json-string-from-sqldatareader, mark as answer if the above has helped you

Comment: sure,can you please re edit this syntax  sb.Append("["{tittle:).append("["{duration:"); like this way

Comment: i already create a  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("{");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123504/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-mr-cool).

Comment: did you sort this out ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also return a Tuple although I feel a custom class is a much better solution. -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>> GetData()
{
    List<Tuple<string,string> results = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.Connection))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select TITTLE,VALUE from T_PROJECTS ", con);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
                results.add(new Tuple<string,string>(reader["TITLE"].ToString(),reader["VALUE"].ToString()));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```